# Why is this homomorphism between homology groups injective?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I fear that I am missing something obvious, but I'm working thru Hatcher and am stuck on the diagram on p139.  He states that the j homomorphisms are injective.   Why?  The map is of course between homology groups, but given the spaces in question, an injective map is (for me) unexpected.

Comment: For those of us who don't have the text at hand, can you define the homomorphisms?

Comment: I'm on an iPad, so this may not be pretty:    j:Hn(Xn)-->Hn(Xn/Xn-1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The homomorphism is obtained from the long exact sequence of the pair $(X^n,X^{n-1})$, namely: $$\ldots\to H_n(X^{n-1})\overset{i_n}\to H_n(X^n)\overset{j_n}\to H_n(X^n,X^{n-1})\overset{\partial_n}\to H_{n-1}(X^{n-1})\to\ldots$$ Lemma 2.34(b), directly preceding the diagram you are studying, tells us that $H_n(X^{n-1})=0$. Therefore, from the exact sequence above we have that $$0\to H_n(X^n)\overset{j_n}\to H_n(X^n,X^{n-1})$$ is exact. But this means precisely that $j_n$ is injective.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.